# Using global variables in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, global-variables

How can I pass data from one view controller to another in `objective-c`? I know in `swift` I would have just created a global variable outside the class declaration, but in `objective-c` is there any way to pass data from the selected cell to a new view that is shown when the user selects that cell?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BarInfoCell"];

    [cell textLabel].text = [[bars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];

    NSString *barAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@ %@", [[bars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"address"],
                            [[bars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"state"],
                            [[bars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"zip"]];

    [cell detailTextLabel].text = barAddress;
    return cell; 
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailSeg" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: Why would you use a global variable in Swift? The choice of language shouldn't change the approach. In either language, a global variable is the wrong way to pass data for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider you want to send string data to ViewController2,ViewController3 from ViewController1.

Make property of the string variable in ViewController2 and ViewController3.

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *str;
```

And while pushing the ViewController2 and ViewController3:

```
ViewController2 *viewController = [ViewController2 alloc]init];
viewController2.str = @"Some text";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];
```

And you have the data send from ViewController1 in ViewController2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` little like this,

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailSeg" sender:indexPath];
}
```

You can send data from one view to another view if there is segue with `UINavigationController` in `prepareForSegue` methos like,

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailSeg"]) {
    NextViewContorller nVC = (NextViewContorller)segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *ip = (NSIndexPath *)sender;

    //You need to define variable in which you want to pass data, in this case value1,value2
    //WAY 1
    NSString *barAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@ %@", [[bars objectAtIndex:ip.row] objectForKey:@"address"],
                            [[bars objectAtIndex:ip.row] objectForKey:@"state"],
                            [[bars objectAtIndex:ip.row] objectForKey:@"zip"]];

    nVC.value1 = [[bars objectAtIndex:ip.row] objectForKey:@"name"]
    nVC.value2 = barAddress;


    //OR
    //WAY 2
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip];
    nVC.value1 = cell.textLabel.text;
    nVC.value2 = cell.detailTextLabel.text;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is steps that provide help to pass data from one `UIViewController` to another `UIViewController`.

**Step 1 :** Declare property to objective-c object in second `UIViewController` (.h file). The object may be whatever like `NSDictionary`, `NSArray` etc. here i have created property for `NSString`.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *strTitle;
```

**Step 2:** You have the object of another `UIViewController` when you are going from one `UIViewController` to another `UIViewController`. once you have object and if you created `property` like **step 1** then you can access the created property with class object like as below.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailSeg"]) {

        DetailViewController * objDetails = (DetailViewController * )segue.destinationViewController;
        objDetails.strTitle = "Hello";
    }
}
```